# Why OS X doesn't have graphic editor?

Tags: macos

Numbers, Keynote, GarageBand, iMovie but no app like Photoshop?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of Photoshop-like applications in the App Store (and, if you take Gimp for example, also outside), so what exactly is your question here? Please be aware that questions about why Apple does or doesn't do something are out of scope.

Comment: Photos ?  Perhaps not as capable as Photoshop but it's right there when you unpack your new Mac.

Answer (score 3):

While Preview isn't the best graphic editor per se, it does the job. You can draw smart objects (which are movable after plotting/saving), resize and crop images, create textboxes and perform some basic adjustments like editing the brightness, contrast, color levels, etc.

[image: The color adjustment menu]